# Explode surname and name by lower/upper

Tags: php, string, uppercase, lowercase

How can I separate firstname and surname from a string like this:

> Pietro DE GIOVANNI

(`Pietro` being the firstname and `DE GIOVANNI` the surname)

I used to do it with an `explode()` on the spaces, but obviously it doesn't work on a person like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surname is always all caps? If so a regex like `(?<givenname>[A-Z][a-z]+) (?<surname>[A-Z ]+)`  could do. Can you add more samples to the question?

Comment: What do you mean it "obviously doesn't work on a person like that"? Sounds like 1 more check to me, pretty simple

Comment: You can explode the string on spaces and loop it, then check with `ctype_upper()` if the element is uppercase or not. Then glue together the words which are purely uppercase, and those who are not separately.

Comment: Once combined, you cannot split first name and last name again and always expect the correct result.

Comment: @chris85: I have a cousin named McKenzie, first name.

Comment: Surname is always all uppercase. Name is all lowercase but the first letter. There could be second names

Comment: @Qirel how would you process a name that does not contain just letters? An apostrophe also can appear in names (as can many other characters).

Comment: Maybe `(?<givenname>(?:[A-Z](?:[a-z]+[A-Z]*)+ )+)(?<surname>['A-Z ]+)` does it? https://regex101.com/r/sf2ude/1/

Comment: That's a good point, @Arjan. Also, the suggestion in the comment won't work with `James R. DOE` - is `R.` a first or surname? My comment above doesn't account for either of those.

Comment: I think item 30 of the [list of falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode on the names by spaces as before, then loop the result as individual pieces of the name. Check with `ctype_upper()` if the string is purely uppercase or not, and append it to the proper variable.

Putting it into a function, it may look like this

```
function split_name($fullname) {
    $firstname = "";
    $surname = "";

    $pieces = explode(" ", $fullname);
    foreach ($pieces as $name) {
        if (ctype_upper($name))
            $surname .= $name." ";
        else
            $firstname .= $name. " ";
    }
    return array("firstname" => $firstname, "surname" => $surname);
}
```

You can then use it as such

```
$name = "Pietro DE GIOVANNI";
$split = split_name($name);
echo "Firstname: ".$split['firstname']."\nSurname: ".$split['surname'];
```

**Note**
This doesn't work for names such as `James O'RILEY`, `John-Paul JOHNSON` or `John. F. KENNEDY`. The first two we can circumvent by stripping away any characters that's not `a-zA-Z` before comparing with `ctype_upper()`, but the latter we won't be able to distinguish if it's a firstname or surname - there's not enough data to say either way. You can *assume* that it's always a part of the firstname (for instance), and/or check if it's after we've started looking at the surnames (if a name in capital letters has been found yet). You can take care of the first two cases by checking for

```
if (ctype_upper(filter_var(str_replace("'", "", $name), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)))
```

instead of using the `if` statement in the original codeblock. This removes quotes and any non-`a-zA-Z` values.

Here's a [**live demo**](https://3v4l.org/JXp2s) where I've stripped away names that contain any characters beside `a-zA-Z`, which would account for the two first issues.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much!